# Create divs with condition for each object in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a box that will contain information from each object in my array that has user_id = 1.

So in this condition 2 boxes should be created in the html.

```
"data": [
{
"id": 1,
"user_id": 1,
"name": "James Smith"
},
{
"id": 2,
"user_id": 1,
"name": "Rebecka Gordon"
},
{
"id": 3,
"user_id": 2,
"name": "Carl Gonzales"
},
]


$.each(data.data, function (index, value) {

    if (this.user_id == 1) {

      console.log(this);

        $('.container').html($('<div>', {class: 'box'}));

    }

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/) functionality of `html()` method is: "Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements."

Which means that even though you match two objects in your loop you set the content of `'.container'` element to the same thing twice.

Insted of `.html()` use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
$.each(data.data, function (index, value) {
```

you used data.data, but data is sufficient to reference the array:

```
$.each( data, function( index, value ){
```

In this line:

```
if (this.user_id == 1) {
```

this is not referencing the array, you have it in value:

```
if (value.user_id == 1) {
```

`.html` would get you a reference to the specific DOM element, but help to add a new one. `.append` would do that:

```
$('.container').append('<div></div>')
```

All together it should be :

```
$.each( data, function( index, value ){
    if (value.user_id == 1) {

       $('.container').append('<div class="box">I am a box</div>');    

    }

});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L83d384s/)